# SoftwareSerial + Serial.printlen() not working properly

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, softwareserial, string

I want to read a SMS message , find it's length and do some "substring();" operation on received SMS. My last two(2) statements do not work . How can I get correct answers? What are correct codes ?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2,3);

String TelephoneNumberText="";

void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(13, LOW); 

  mySerial.begin(9600);   
  Serial.begin(9600);                
  delay(100);  

  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1\r");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode 
  delay(500);  
}

void loop()   
{

 while(mySerial.available())
  {
   char s;
   s = mySerial.read(); 
   TelephoneNumberText = TelephoneNumberText + s;                     
   } 


 Serial.println(TelephoneNumberText);           // this statement works

 Serial.println(TelephoneNumberText.length());  // this statement dose not works

 Serial.println(TelephoneNumberText.substring(0,3));// this statement dose not works



} // end loop
```

Comment: Serial.println(TelephoneNumberText);           // this statement works

Serial.println(TelephoneNumberText.length());  // this statement dose not works

Serial.println(TelephoneNumberText.substring(0,3));// this statement dose not works      /* please tell me correct codes for above two(2) statements */

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure a string like this can be used?

Better anyway to not each time let a dynamic string be created, but use a fixed string e.g.

```
char TelephoneNumberText[16];
```

Set the length of the max number, and change other string functions accordingly.